# Manipulating and grouping strings within a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, regex, for-loop, python-re

Hi I would like to add a bit to the `code` where it splits the `notes` into two parts `configurations` and `parameters`. The `configurations` resides inside the `[]` of the `notes` and is to the left of the curly brackets `()`. The `parameters` however resides inside of the curly brackets `()`. For the `notes` that have `parameters` I want to split them up using a commas. If a `parameter` has one or more `configurations` a list that contains all `elements` of the `config` is separated by **commas** [`element 1, element 2]`. For `parameters` without any `configs` create and **empty list** `[]`. If a **note** has **no parameters** then both the `parameter` and `configuration` section will be of type `None`. I want to achieve the results from the **Expected Outputs** below.

Code:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

lines = ['yes hello there', 'move on to the next command if the previous command was successful.',
         "$$n:describes the '&&' character in the RUN command.",
         'k', 
         '$$n[t(a1), mfc(s,expand,rr), np(), k]: description']

notes = []
parameters= []
configurations= []
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if re.search(r'\$\$.*\:', line):
        notes.append(re.sub(r'\$\$.*\:', '', line).strip())
        
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Note': notes,
    'Parameters': parameters,
    'configurations': configurations
})
```

Expected Output:

```
+----+------------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------------------+
|    | Note                                           | Parameters   | Configurations           |
|----+------------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------------------|
|  0 | describes the && character in the RUN command. | None         | None                     |
|  1 | description                                    | t,mfc,np,k   | [a1],[s,expand,rr],[],[] |
+----+------------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create sublists:

```
notes = []
parameters= []
configurations= []
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    expr = re.search(r'\$\$[^:[]*?(?:\[([^:\]]*)\])?\:', line)
    if expr:
        notes.append(re.sub(r'\$\$.*?\:', '', line).strip())
        if expr[1]:
            names = []
            confs = []
            for part in re.findall(r'([^(,]+)(?:\(([^)]*)\))?', expr[1]):
                names.append(part[0])
                confs.append(part[1].split(",") if part[1] else [])
            parameters.append(names)
            configurations.append(confs)
        else:
            parameters.append(None)
            configurations.append(None)
```

If you need those values to be strings instead of sublists, then:

```
notes = []
parameters= []
configurations= []
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    expr = re.search(r'\$\$[^:[]*?(?:\[([^:\]]*)\])?\:', line)
    if expr:
        notes.append(re.sub(r'\$\$.*?\:', '', line).strip())
        if expr[1]:
            names = []
            confs = []
            for part in re.findall(r'([^\s(,]+)(?:\(([^)]*)\))?', expr[1]):
                names.append(part[0])
                confs.append(f"[{part[1]}]")
            parameters.append(",".join(names))
            configurations.append(",".join(confs))
        else:
            parameters.append(None)
            configurations.append(None)
```